# Module not found: Mysql.connector

Tags: python, mysql, module, syntax-error, mysql-connector

I am working on connectivity for a project, but importing mysql.connector is showing a 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'' error. This isn't an issue with the code, either, since I have tried importing it in completely blank file.

I have tried using pip to install it, as was suggested by other threads, but it just shows syntax errors. I have installed the folder directly and put it in the Lib folder, and it still shows the same error. I have tried to install both python and sql on three separate devices, and this has been repeatedly happening on every device I use, regardless of the OS.

I am not quite sure what to try next.

Comment: which error exactly or must we guess?

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'

Comment: Please add the pip error messages, I had the problem that pyspark would get downloaded completely so I tried it several times a day to nstall it, till it really n through

Comment: >>> pip install mysql-connector-python
SyntaxError: invalid syntax @nbk

Comment: enter in the searchbar cmd then enter and then `pip install mysql-connector-python` works like a charm

Comment: >pip install mysql-connector-python
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. @nbk

Comment: then go to the folder where you installed python and runf the command from there, in my case python is in the PATH string

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean? I am very new to all this, sorry @nbk

Comment: start a explorer window search for pip.exe the navogate in the dos coamnd shell with `cd ..` ( gom one folder up) `cd foldername` to enter the folder to the folder where the pip.exe is located and then enzter the command  OR https://datatofish.com/add-python-to-windows-path/